# How to delete Dev tagged docker images in hosted group of Nexus Repository

Tags: nexus

Am trying to delete Dev tagged docker images in hosted group of Nexus Repository. Can anyone provide clear procedure to do it by once which means using some scripts or any alternate methods.

Answer (score 0):

There's information on removing docker images in the [cleanup guide](https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Cleanup+Policies#CleanupPolicies-DockerCleanupStrategies).  If you just want to remove a single image you can use the UI or REST API to delete the manifest.  Layers may be used by other images (especially in the case you're deleting a tag) so it's adviced to use the tasks described therein (any mention of cleanup is because it's the cleanup guide and isn't relavent to an individual removal).